# Removing a row of data that contains values more than two standard deviations away from the mean

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

So I have a list of lists as my dataset X. I computed the means and standard deviations of each row and stored them each into their own list. My goal is finding which rows of X have outliers (values that are more than two standard deviations away from the mean) and deleting the entire row. I have only accomplished removing the outliers from a single test list and not a list of lists:

```
from math import sqrt

def std_dev(lst): # standard deviation function
     mean = float(sum(lst)) / len(lst)
     return sqrt(sum((x - mean)**2 for x in lst) / len(lst))

def compute_std(X):
     std = []
     std.append([std_dev(char) for char in X])
     return std

std = compute_std(X)

def means(lst):
     return float(sum(lst)) / len(lst)

def compute_mean(X):
     mean = []
     mean.append([means(chars) for chars in X])
     return mean

mean = compute_mean(X)

final_list1 = [x for x in X if (x > mean - 2 * std)]
final_list = [x for x in final_list1 if (x < mean + 2 * std)]
```

The last two lines of code have only worked on a single list and I want it to iterate through each list in X. I am new to python and list comprehension.

Comment: [statistics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) already has mean and (sample) stddev.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Yes, I know. I am more confused about the list comprehension part.

Answer (score 1):

I did not use a list comprehension to get the valid rows of `X`, and I'm not sure I have found the qualifying rows correctly, (with the stdev and mean).

Perhaps someone else can create a comprehension, but I thought there were too many calculations (mean, stddev, and the comparison) to make a succinct list comprehension.

```
from statistics import mean, stdev
from random import randint, seed

#seed(1)

X = []
final_list = []

for i in range(10):
    M = []
    for j in range(25):
        M.append(randint(-25, 1000))
    X.append(M)

for row in X:
    sd = stdev(row)
    avg = mean(row)
    #print(avg, sd)
    
    high = avg + 2 * sd
    low = avg - 2 * sd

    if all(low < num < high for num in row):
        final_list.append(row)

print(len(final_list))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Could you explain what you did in the first block of code starting with "for i in range(10)"?

Comment: @c_collins That creates 10 lists (appended to `X`) where each of the lists contains 25 random ints from -25 to 1000. I just did that to create a sample `X` of 10 lists with 25 random numbers in each of the 10 lists. That just gives some sample values to apply the stdev and mean functions to later in the code.